# How can I run my live server & compile sass using node-sass simultaneously using a single command?

Tags: npm, sass, node-sass

I want to run my **app.js** using  **"dev" : "nodemon app.js"**
and I have also added **"node-sass": "node-sass public/sass/main.scss public/css/style.css -w"**

My goal is to run live server using nodemon app.js only once.
And compile sass to css everytime I edit my sass file and press **ctrl + S** without restarting my server.

I have tried it by adding **"dev": " nodemon app.js && node-sass public/sass/main.scss public/css/style.css -w"** .This command is running server successfully but its not compiling my sass to css whenever im trying Ctrl + s on sass file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both commands on seperate terminals.
Click the plus sign to open the terminal in the same directory or use git bash.
[image]

Comment: This works! Sounds so simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make another script merging both commands in your `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
  "dev":"nodemon app.js",
  "node-sass":"node-sass public/sass/main.scss public/css/style.css -w",
  "dev:sass":"npm-run-all --parallel node-sass dev" 
}
```

By executing `dev:sass,` you will run both commands in parallel (note the `--parallel` flag).

Note: You have to install the `"npm-run-all"` devDependency to make the script work.